# Image pixel manipulation in a dedicated web worker

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, html5-canvas, web-worker

I need to do a computation intensive image pixel manipulation in a browser using JavaScript. Pixel manipulation includes histogram equalization, converting to grayscale using lightness (L* of CIE Lab color space).

To not block the UI thread, I want to perform this pixel manipulation in a dedicated web worker.

The processed image is not going to be directly drawn to the canvas only once. The image can be zoomed and panned, some other shapes will be drawn on top of it. Thus, I can't use `canvas.transferControlToOffscreen()`.

I came up with a solution to create an `OffsceenCanvas` using the constructor, draw the image and get the `ImageData`. Then send the `ImageData` as a transferable object to the worker `worker.postMessage(imageData, [imageData.data.buffer])` and after processing it send it back from the worker to the main thread `self.postMessage(imageData, [imageData.data.buffer])`.

Is it an optimal solution or there are other more efficient patterns?

`main.js`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const zoom = 1, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
const offscreen, offscreenCtx;

const draw = () => {
  if (!offscreen) {
    return;
  }
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.save();
  // simplified zooming and panning
  ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
  ctx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
  ctx.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0);
  ctx.restore();
};

canvas.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    zoom *= 1.1;
  } else {
    zoom /= 1.1;
  }
  draw();
});

const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url), {
  type: 'module',
});
worker.addEventListener('message', message => {
  const imageData = message.data;
  offscreenCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  draw();
});

const image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  offscreen = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height);
  offscreenCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  offscreenCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  const imageData = offscreenCtx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  // clear the offscreen canvas to make sure the unprocessed image can't be sh
  offscreenCtx.clearRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  worker.postMessage(imageData, [imageData.data.buffer]);
});

document.getElementById('image-select').addEventListener('change', e) => {
  const files = e.target.files;
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    const file = files[0];
    if (/image\/.*/.test(file.type)) {
      image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
  }
});
```

`worker.js`

```js
self.addEventListener('message', message => {
  const imageData = message.data;
  pixelManipulation(imageData);
  self.postMessage(imageData, [imageData.data.buffer]);
  self.close();
});
```

Comment: The line `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);` is redundant overhead, `putImageData` will overwrite existing pixels so there is no need to clear. If you create a worker once and have it do nothing until needed it can save you a tiny bit of time as you avoid the overhead of creating a new JS execution context each time you load the image. Best to create the worker in idle time before you need it as the first instantiation of a new worker can be noticable.

Comment: @Blindman67 clearRect here could have served the purpose of not showing the unprocessed image while it is being processed. But given it's an OffscreenCanvas for which we see the full scope, and that can't get rendered anywhere else, I wonder what's the actual point of the whole snippet.

Comment: I modified the code snippet to be more similar to the real code. The `clearRect` is needed to not show the unprocessed image during the time the image has been already loaded and hasn't been processed yet. In the sample code snippet this is possible due to the `draw()` call in the mouse wheel listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The image can be zoomed and panned, some other shapes will be drawn on top of it. Thus, I can't use canvas.transferControlToOffscreen().

Not sure how you come to that conclusion here. You can very well draw zoomed or panned images over an `OffcreenCanvas` that lives in a worker and renders over a placeholder canvas.
The only issue would be handling events, but you could still do this from the main thread and send only the drawing params to you worker, or I wrote an [`EventPort` prototype](https://github.com/Kaiido/EventPort.js) some time ago that helps for this kind of scenario.

---

Now, if you really don't want all your code to live in the Worker thread, you can still move most of what you are doing there.

Do not use an `HTMLImageElement` to load and decode your image, instead use `createImageBitmap(Blob)` from the worker thread directly, this means that you'll have to `fetch()` your image yourself, but you'll save processing.

*[Note]
We unfortunately still don't have an [`ImageBitmap#getImageData()`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4785) method, but a potentially better performing path than through an `OffscreenCanvas` is to use a `VideoFrame` and then copy its data into a buffer, though it's still experimental (only in Chromium browsers) and we [still don't have a way to enforce an RGBA format](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/issues/92), so I'll keep it hidden for now, but it may still be useful.*

```js
async function readImageData(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (!resp.ok) { throw "Network Error"; }
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  const { width, height } = bmp;
  if ("VideoFrame" in window) {
    const frame = new VideoFrame(bmp, { timestamp: 0 })
    bmp.close();
    const { format } = frame;
    if (format !== "RGBA" || format !== "RGBX") {
      console.warn("This image would require a special parsing logic for: ", format);
    }
    const arr = new Uint8Array(frame.allocationSize());
    frame.copyTo(arr);
    frame.close();
    return { width, height, data: arr, format: frame.format };
  }
  console.warn("using legacy canvas2d.getImageData()");
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bmp.width, bmp.height);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
  bmp.close();
  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
}

readImageData("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Elakha.jpg/320px-Elakha.jpg")
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

So we have the decoding of the image in the worker, the extraction of the pixels data, you have the processing, now remains the conversion of the `ImageData` to bitmap, that you do when you call `putImageData()`.
Zooming and panning an `ImageData` implies a two step rasterization, where you first rasterize untransformed and then transform that bitmap.
So instead of passing the `ImageData` to you main thread, use once more `createImageBitmap()` passing the `ImageData` object, and send the resulting `ImageBitmap` to the rendering thread instead. You'll be able to do your transform from there directly:

```js
const workerContent = document.querySelector("[type=worker]").textContent;
const workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerContent], { type: "text/javascript" }));
const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
worker.onmessage = ({data: bmp}) => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  // Rendering rotated 90deg
  canvas.width = bmp.height;
  canvas.height = bmp.width;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, -bmp.width/2, -bmp.height/2);
};
worker.postMessage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Elakha.jpg/320px-Elakha.jpg");
```

```html
<script type="worker">
  function process({ data }) {
    for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
      const r = data[i];
      data[i] = data[i+1];
      data[i+1] = r;
    }
  };
  onmessage = async ({ data: url }) => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    if (!resp.ok) { throw "Network Error"; }
    const blob = await resp.blob();
    const source = await createImageBitmap(blob);
    const { width, height } = source;
    // Using  legacy context2d.getImageData() for now.
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(width, height);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
    ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
    source.close(); // free memory, we don't need it anymore
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    process(imageData);
    const bmp = await createImageBitmap(imageData);
    // Transferring the ImageBitmap auto closes it.
    self.postMessage(bmp, [bmp]);
  }
</script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

Finally, **DO NOT CREATE ONE SHOT WORKERS**, write your code in ways it's reusable. Starting a worker is an heavy operation, keeping it alive is fine in comparison.
So if you need to process multiple images or even if you need to do other works in another thread, keep that worker alive and make it handle all these jobs.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. According to the https://caniuse.com/createimagebitmap as of July 2023 , the `createImageBitmap` has browser support 94.28%. Safari supports this feature since version 15 only. Safari and Firefox only partially support this feature. Safari support is crucial in my case.

Comment: The support is the same as of OffscreenCanvas. "partial support" refers to the lack of support of the resizing and premultiplyAlpha options, that you don't need.

Comment: Indeed OffscreenCanvas has browser support 88.93% and Safari supports it from version 16.2 https://caniuse.com/offscreencanvas. `createImageBitmap` is a clear winner here. Thanks.

Comment: Since I always have a `File` (a result of selecting files using the `<input>`) which is a `Blob`, I probably don't need to do `(await fetch(url)).blob()` in the worker. How do you recommend to transfer a blob to a worker? `worker.postMessage(file)` or `worker.postMessage(URL.createObjectURL(file))` and `fetch` this URL in the worker?

Comment: Definitely pass the file directly, a File object is just a pointer so no actual data is copied.